# Access Java Documentation from Eclipse IDE

Tags: java, eclipse

I installed **Java SE 14** and **Eclipse IDE**. Now I want to access the Java official documentation from the Eclipse IDE itself. How do I achieve this?

Note : I looked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4600172/how-do-i-add-the-java-api-documentation-to-eclipse) question. I found out that adding `src.zip` to the jre library in eclipse will work. But I didn't find `src.zip` in my jdk-14.0.1 folder. May be the recent versions didn't include `src.zip`.

Other details :

- Downloaded Java from [here](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase-downloads.html)
- Windows 10
- Eclipse IDE 2020-06 edition

Comment: how did you install jdk 14?

Comment: For the Linux version, it's in the `lib` subfolder.

Comment: What OS are you using?

Comment: @tobias_k On Linux it's there only if the `openjdk-src` package (or whatever the name is, depending on the distro) it's been installed.

Comment: (I was referring to when downloading from https://jdk.java.net/ )

Comment: Which Eclipse version do you have exactly (see _Help > About Eclipse IDE_)? Configuring the JDK in _Window > Preferences: Java > Installed JREs_ should be enough to use it in projects and to see the source code of the system library.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure why I cannot find `src.zip` in the jdk installation directory. So I reinstalled it. When I reinstalled the jdk 14 I found the `src.zip` in that directory. Here is the path of that folder : `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-14.0.1\lib\src`.

And it is not even required for me to attach this source to the eclipse. Eclipse automatically detected the source and attached it.

Answer (score 1):

Open your eclipse IDE and go to

> windows option -> show view -> javadoc

after choosing that you can view a Javadoc tab in the below panel. Like this
[image]
Initially, it will be blank. when you choose a library function you can view the official Javadoc details in this panel. You need not download or configure any source file for this.

Comment: It didn't work. When I viewed the details of a library method in javadoc it displayed "Note: This element neither has attached source nor attached Javadoc and hence no Javadoc could be found."

Comment: This blog discusses the solutions to fix the above error you reported.https://crunchify.com/in-eclipse-how-to-fix-this-element-neither-has-attached-source-nor-attached-javadoc-and-hence-no-javadoc-could-be-found/

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6406300/how-to-view-javadoc-in-eclipse please go through this. It might help you.

Comment: You are right. I need not configure any source file. I was able to solve my problem when I reinstalled jdk.